# Lightning carousele style

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

I want to display products images on Product record page and I'm using custom component with Lightning Carousele, it's possible to change styles? ( I want to have images much smaller and fit cover).

Comment: Can you please show some code or some images what exactly you want.

Comment: Maybe i will try to tell you. My code works properly, i have images in carousle. But the size of carousle is adjustable to the biggest one image. But for example i want to display all images in the same size, very much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no styling hooks available for the [lightning-carousel component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-carousel-image/documentation) so you're better off re-implementing it from the [LDS blueprint](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/carousel/#CSS-Class-Overview).